# Error in parsing Json object, when this object has a property with html tag

Tags: c#, html, json

I have a Json file that on of the properties has html tags. But in Deserializing object to Json, I run into an error exception

```js
 [
        {
            "Subject": "Úáí",
            "SenderName": "ÏÑíÇÝÊ ˜ääÏÇä",
            "ReceiversName": "ÏÑíÇÝÊ",
            "CcReceiversName": "ãåã",
            "SentDate": "1393-03-03",
   "Status":"1",
   "HasAttachment":true,
   "Priority":"1",
   "Privacy":"1",
   "SentDateString":"1394/02/03",
   "IsForward":true,
   "IsReplied":true,
   "InboxId":"97002F44-BDC2-483D-A6CC-51A6479FB272",
   "ReferenceNumber":"1",
   "RefrenceDate":"1393-03-03",
   "ReferenceHasNote":true,
   "Labels":"test",
   "IsRead":true,
   "IsStarred":true,
   "IsImportant":true,
   "IsInInbox":true,
   "PriorityTitle":"ãåã",
   "PrivacyTitle":"ÓÑí",
   "RefrenceId":"97002F44-BDC2-483D-A6CC-51A6479FB272",
   "ReplyDeadLine":"1393-03-03",
   "HasPrevious":true,
   "TextBody": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body><table style="width:100%">  <tr>    <td>Jill</td>    <td>Smith</td>     <td>50</td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>Eve</td>    <td>Jackson</td>     <td>94</td>  </tr></table></body></html>",
   
        }
    ]
```

exception :

Connection 'Mail': After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: w. Path '[0].TextBody', line 29, position 86.

Comment: You know - JSON and HTML are different things. First one has many curly braces, and second one has many angular braces.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes. You right, but solution for this issue??

Comment: solution is - google for parsing HTML

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ,  
I have Updated my Question, Please view It.

Comment: What is the C# model that your are deserialising into?

Answer (score 1):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` should accept [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) inputs.
You have specified it an HTML tags, that aren't even XML which is also unacceptable.

If you need to parse HTML tags, than [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) will be a better solutions for it.

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Comment: this string taged wirh html tags, is a user input that fill in CkEditor

Comment: I have Updated my Question, Please view It.

Comment: You did a big mistake, You should never do such a critic change after you ask a question, This is violating the rules. You should open a new question.